# Prove the following trigonometric identity.

Tags: trigonometry

$$\frac{\sin x - \cos x +1}{\sin x + \cos x -1}=\frac{\sin x +1}{\cos x}$$

I tried substituting $\sin^2x+\cos^2x = 1$ but I cannot solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above method is really verifying and always quick. Another method to arrive at the answer is by rationalising denominator (mainly when the answer [or RHS] is not known or one is asked to work out only from LHS to RHS):

$$\frac{\sin x - \cos x + 1 }{\sin x + \cos x - 1 }\cdot \frac{\sin x + \cos x + 1}{\sin x + \cos x + 1}$$

$$\frac{ (\sin x + 1)^2 - \cos^2 x }{ 2 \sin x \cos x } $$

$$ \frac{ \sin^2 x + 2 \sin x + 1 - \cos^2 x }{ 2 \sin x \cos x } $$

$$ \frac{  \sin^2 x + 2 \sin x + \sin^2 x + \cos^2 x - \cos^2 x } {2 \sin x \cos x } $$

and the answer follows i.e. $$ \frac{\sin x + 1}{\cos x}. $$

Hope it was helpful.

Comment: well done i say :)

Comment: I wouldn't call this rationalizing the denominator, as there's nothing necessarily rational or irrational about the denominator before or after the initial multiplication, but this technique does mirror the technique for rationalizing denominators: using *conjugates*.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac c d\iff ad=bc$$

Comment: and obviously this is allowed when $(b,d)\not=0$ which is when $x \not=\pi/2 + k\pi$ and $x\not=k\pi$

Comment: Exactly what's needed here! +1

Answer (score 1):

$(\sin x- \cos x+1)\cos x = \sin x \cos x -\cos^2 x +\cos x$

$(\sin x+ \cos x-1)(\sin x +1) = \sin^2 x + \sin x \cos x +\cos x -1 = \sin x \cos x +\cos x +(\sin^2 x -1)= \sin x \cos x -\cos^2 x +\cos x$

Answer (score 0):

As always, the method that "always" (never say "never" OR "always"...) work is the substitution $ t = \tan \frac{x}{2},$ which makes $\sin(x) = \frac{2x}{1+x^2}, \cos(x)= \frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2},$ which makes an identity like this a mechanical verification.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that the Right Hand side $\displaystyle\frac{\sin x+1}{\cos x}=\tan x+\sec x$

So, I want to utilize $\displaystyle\sec^2x-\tan^2x=1$

Dividing  the numerator & the denominator by $\cos x,$

$$\frac{\sin x - \cos x +1}{\sin x + \cos x -1}=\frac{\tan x-1+\sec x}{\tan x+1-\sec x}$$

$$=\frac{\tan x+\sec x-(\sec^2x-\tan^2x)}{\tan x+1-\sec x}(\text{ Replacing }1\text{ with } \sec^2x-\tan^2x)$$

$$=\frac{(\sec x+\tan x)-(\sec x+\tan x)(\sec x-\tan x)}{\tan x+1-\sec x}$$

$$=\frac{(\sec x+\tan x)(1-\sec x+\tan x)}{\tan x+1-\sec x}$$

$$=\sec x+\tan x$$

Comment: @dona12, how about this?

Answer (score 0):

I will start like Timotej, but finish differently.

$$\cos x(\sin x-\cos x+1)=\cos x(1+\sin x)-\cos^2x=\cos x(1+\sin x)-(1-\sin^2x)$$
$$=(1+\sin x)\{\cos x-(1-\sin x)\}$$

$$\implies \cos x(\sin x-\cos x+1)=(1+\sin x)(\sin x+\cos x-1)$$

Now change the sides of $\displaystyle \cos x, \sin x+\cos x-1$

---

Let me derive some  other identities

$(1)\displaystyle\sin x(\sin x-\cos x+1)=\sin^2x+\sin x(1-\cos x)=1-\cos^2x+\sin x(1-\cos x)$

$\displaystyle\implies\sin x(\sin x-\cos x+1)=(1-\cos x)(\sin x+\cos x+1)$

$(2)\displaystyle\sin x(\sin x+\cos x-1)=\sin^2x-\sin x(1-\cos x)=(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x-\sin x)$

$(3)\displaystyle\cos x(\sin x+\cos x-1)=\cos^2x-\cos x(1-\sin x)=(1-\sin x)(1+\sin x-\cos x)$

and so on

Comment: @dona12, another method