# Prove $\frac{\sin\theta-\cos\theta+1}{\sin\theta+\cos\theta-1}=\frac{1+\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove by writing: $$\theta = 2A$$ that: 
$$\frac{\sin\theta-\cos\theta+1}{\sin\theta+\cos\theta-1}=\frac{1+\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$$

First I subbed in the $2A$ such that:

$$\frac{\sin 2A-\cos 2A+1}{\sin 2A+\cos 2A-1}=\frac{1+\sin 2A}{\cos 2A}$$

Then I considered the following trigonometric formulae:

$$\begin{align}
\sin 2A &= 2\sin A\cos A \\
\cos 2A &= \cos^{2}A - \sin^{2}A \\
\cos 2A &= 2\cos^{2}A-1 \\
\cos 2A &= 1-2\sin^{2}A
\end{align}$$

I have taken various approaches but keep ending up with:

$$\frac{\cos A+\sin A}{\cos A-\sin A}$$
on the left hand side.
But I can't seem to get the right hand side to agree with this.
I end up with something like:
$$\frac{1+2\sin A\cos A}{1-2\sin^{2}A}$$
I've spent a few hours on this and can't find the solution.
Help appreciated.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426981/need-help-in-proving-that-frac-sin-theta-cos-theta-1-sin-theta-cos

Comment: Related: ["Better proof for $\frac{1+\cos x+\sin x}{1−\cos x+\sin x}\equiv\frac{1+\cos x}{\sin x}$"](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1590059/409)

Comment: One should be a bit careful with these types of identities. For $\theta=-\pi/2$ the left-hand side is defined (and equals 0). But, the right-hand side is not definied. (In fact, one has the indeterminate "$0/0$", which in this case is naturaly extended by taking limits to 0.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.

You say you end up with $1+2\sin A \cos A$ in the numerator, but by the [double angle formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html), $2\sin A \cos A = \sin (2A)$ so you get the numerator of the RHS.

In the denominator you end up with $1-2\sin^2 A$, use a suitable double angle formula for the cosine ($1-2\sin^2 A = \cos(2A)$).

Answer (score 5):

Here is another simple proof, $$LHS=\frac{\sin\theta-\cos\theta+1}{\sin\theta+\cos\theta-1}$$
$$=\frac{(\sin\theta-\cos\theta+1)(\sin\theta+\cos\theta+1)}{(\sin\theta+\cos\theta-1)(\sin\theta+\cos\theta+1)}$$
$$=\frac{(\sin\theta+1)^2-(\cos\theta)^2}{(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)^2-(1)^2}$$
$$=\frac{\sin^2\theta+2\sin\theta+1-\cos^2\theta}{\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta+2\sin\theta\cos\theta-1}$$
$$=\frac{\sin^2\theta+2\sin\theta+\sin^2\theta}{1+2\sin\theta\cos\theta-1}$$
$$=\frac{2\sin^2\theta+2\sin\theta}{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}$$
$$=\frac{2\sin\theta(1+\sin\theta)}{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}$$$$=\frac{1+\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}=RHS$$

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all.
$$\frac{1+2sinAcosA}{cos^2{A}-sin^2{A}}$$
$$=\frac{cos^{2}A+sin^{2}A+2sinAcosA}{cos^{2}A-sin^{2}A}$$
$$=\frac{(cosA+sinA)(cosA+sinA)}{(cosA+sinA)(cosA-sinA)}$$
$$=\frac{cosA+sinA}{cosA-sinA}$$
Time for tea.

Comment: Actually you should use `\sin` and `\cos` to get the properly upright spaced trigonometric functions, but I was too lazy to edit all of them...