# Proving $\frac{\cos a - \sin a + 1}{\cos a + \sin a - 1 } = \frac{\sin a}{1-\cos a}$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing

Can somebody help to prove that:

> $$\frac{\cos a - \sin a + 1}{\cos a + \sin a - 1 } = \frac{\sin a}{1-\cos a}$$

Comment: Please show some efforts first.

Comment: Related: ["Better proof for $\frac{1+\cos x + \sin x}{1 - \cos x + \sin x} \equiv \frac{1+\cos x}{\sin x}$"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590059/better-proof-for-frac1-cos-x-sin-x1-cos-x-sin-x-equiv-frac1/1590203#1590203).

Comment: Multiply by both denominators and cancel out terms. There would be left $1=\sin^2 a+\cos^2 a$.

Comment: Multiply thru by the product of the denominators and simplify. I.e.  if $B\ne 0\ne D$ then $A/B=C/D\iff AD=BC.$

Comment: As requested by Alex, it's generally best for questioners to include a sense of what they know about a problem and where they got stuck, so that potential answerers can target their responses to an appropriate skill level, and without wasting time telling the questioner things that are already known. Posting a problem without this kind of context *looks* like you're just trying to get people to do your homework for you, often resulting in down-votes and/or votes-to-close.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{ \cos a -\sin a +1}{\cos a +\sin a -1} \times \frac{1-\cos a}{1-\cos a} =\frac{\color{red}{\cos a}-\sin a+\overbrace{1-\cos^2 a}^{\sin^2 a}+\sin a \cos a\color{red}{-\cos a}}{(\cos a +\sin a -1)((1-\cos a)} =\frac{\sin a (\cos a +\sin a -1)}{(1-\cos a)(\cos a +\sin a -1)}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks man, it really helped